# Seat reservation requirements for TGV trips entirely within Germany

Tags: germany, sncf

If I have a BahnCard 100 / cancelled by DB ticket, which allows me to take any train, for a TGV trip entirely within Germany (e.g. Karlsruhe to Frankfurt), am I required to reserve a seat?

The DB app tells me no and the DB ticket machine is willing to sell me a ticket without a seat reservation, but the train departure board has the Reservation Required sign.

Comment: What makes you think that a Bahn card 100 gives you the right to use any train in Germany? Normally DB tickets aren’t valid on trains run by other operators. (E.g Flix Train, NightJet, Eurostar/Thalys, etc)

Comment: TGVs in Germany are operated by DB, so are DB trains.

Comment: @KristvanBesien in my experience _TGV_ is typically used in English to refer to French high-speed trains only, so my first reaction to a question about TGV trips entirely in Germany is "there aren't any; you mean _ICE._"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got confirmation from DB: No seat reservation required.

Comment: The real question is: how did you manage to get any information from DB *this fast*?

Comment: @ojdo good ol' Twitter.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 it might be good to add a link to the source in the answer then, as this may change in the future and that tweet might not stay reliable.

Comment: also might be good to link a more permanent reference (think wayback machine but for twitter) together with the direct link.

Comment: @DidierL I can't link to a Twitter DM.